# User Experience Definition

Tags: research, definition

I am a PhD student in computer science, writing a paper on Mobile User Experience. I need to cite a definition for UX. I have found numerous web-sites and and videos with various UX definitions.

However I am having a hard time **finding a scholarly paper from a reputable journal/conference that provides a UX definition.**

If you happen to know of such paper(s) I'd appreciate if you would please refer me to them.

Comment: You should look at the relevant ISO standards. Here's a similar question where I cited the definiton: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/106790/definition-of-human-centred-quality-in-iso-9241-220-separates-usability-and-user

Comment: Do you plan to make this paper public ? I think this community would really appreciate to read it :)

Comment: @Brice: Absolutely. :)

Comment: Agree with @Brice.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you count the ISO standards as a scholarly paper, but the standards are pretty high. You'll also have to check whether this definition is still current in the latest version.

ISO 9241 defines user experience as:

> a person's perceptions and responses that result from the use and/or
>   anticipated use of a product, system or service.

You might also be interested in Don Norman's [definition of User Experience](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/definition-user-experience/):

> "User experience" encompasses all aspects of the end-user's
>   interaction with the company, its services, and its products.

Comment: Great. Surely I will cite that. Do you also happen to know of definitions in mobile domain? (Like the ones that define UX as overall sum of responsiveness, findability, discoverabilty, etc)

Comment: Behnam are you able to cite those mobile-domain definitions that define it as overall sum of responsiveness, findability, etc? It seems so specific that I have to I wonder if you haven't already encountered this definition you're looking for somewhere before.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the historical perspective on conference proceedings, such as:

**Towards a shared definition of user experience**. In: Proceedings of ACM CHI 2008 Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems April 5-10, 2008, . pp. 2395-2398

**Understanding, scoping and defining user experience: a survey approach**. In: INTERACT 2009: Human-Computer Interaction – INTERACT 2009 pp 922-923

From printed books I would consider citing the foundational book by Garrett, which contributed to define the field, despite the non-academical tone of voice:

Garrett, J.J. **The Elements of User Experience: User-Centered Design for the Web and Beyond.** Second edition (p6)

> User experience is about how [a product or service] works on the
>   outside, where a person comes into contact with it. When someone asks
>   you what it’s like to use a product or service, they’re asking about
>   the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [link](https://scholar.google.co.in/scholar?q=user%20experience&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5).

Apart from that there few research papers
http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01449290500330331

http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1518813

http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1358693

Hope this helps!! All the best.

Comment: Can you share the relevant definitions in your answer? Those links may disappear in the future.